# How to read rules from a file

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to match the sentence against rules.

I am able to compile multiple rules and match it against `CoreLabel` using the following method :

```
TokenSequencePattern pattern1 = TokenSequencePattern.compile("([{tag:/NN.*//*}])");
TokenSequencePattern pattern2 = TokenSequencePattern.compile("([{tag:/NN.*//*}])");

List<TokenSequencePattern> tokenSequencePatterns = new ArrayList<>();
tokenSequencePatterns.add(pattern1);
tokenSequencePatterns.add(pattern2);

MultiPatternMatcher multiMatcher = TokenSequencePattern.getMultiPatternMatcher(tokenSequencePatterns);
List<SequenceMatchResult<CoreMap>> matched=multiMatcher.findNonOverlapping(tokens);
```

I have many rules inside a file. Is there any way to load the rule file?

I have seen a method to load the rules from file using the following method:

```
CoreMapExpressionExtractor extractor = CoreMapExpressionExtractor.createExtractorFromFiles(TokenSequencePattern.getNewEnv(), "en.rules");
List<MatchedExpression> matched = extractor.extractExpressions((CoreMap)sentence);
```

But it accepts `CoreMap` as its argument. But I need to match it against `CoreLabel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this comprehensive write up on TokensRegex:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/tokensregex.html